# Cannot enable CustomSecuritySample for SSRS2016

Tags: c#, windows, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I cannot manage to get the Customer security sample provided from Microsoft to work. I have followed the README for CustomerSecuritySample here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample

### Expected result

I expected that after a restart of the services a logon screen should be provided when entering http://computername/Reports in the browser. But instead I still get an Windows authentication prompt. I think that I miss some final steps in the guide that needs to be done to make it work but cannot figure out what

## Setup

Instance name: SQL2016
URL set in Reporting Services Configuration Manager: http://computername/Reports

## Configuration steps taken

The following changes have been made where I followed the README:

### RSReportServer.config:

Set AuthenticationTypes to Custom:

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
  <Custom/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
```

Replaced UI with new data:

```
<UI>
  <CustomAuthenticationUI>
    <loginUrl>/Pages/UILogon.aspx</loginUrl>
    <UseSSL>False</UseSSL>
    <PassThroughCookies>
      <PassThroughCookie>sqlAuthCookie</PassThroughCookie>
    </PassThroughCookies>
  </CustomAuthenticationUI>
  <ReportServerUrl>http://computername/Reports</ReportServerUrl>
  <PageCountMode>Estimate</PageCountMode>
</UI>
```

Replaced Security extension information with:

```
<Extension Name="Forms" 
  Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.Authorization, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity" >
  <Configuration>
    <AdminConfiguration>
      <UserName>username</UserName>
    </AdminConfiguration>
  </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

Replaced Authentication extension with:

```
<Extension Name="Forms" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.AuthenticationExtension,Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity" />
```

### RSSrvPolicy.config:

Added a new code group:

```
<CodeGroup
  class="UnionCodeGroup"
  version="1"
  Name="SecurityExtensionCodeGroup"
  Description="Code group for the sample security extension"
  PermissionSetName="FullTrust">
  <IMembershipCondition
    class="UrlMembershipCondition"
    version="1"
    Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.SQL2016\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.dll"/>
</CodeGroup>
```

### Web.config:

Added under system.web:

```
<machineKey validationKey="GENERATED_VALIDATION_KEY" decryptionKey="GENERATED_DECRYPTION_KEY" validation="AES" decryption="AES" />
```

Changed authentication mode from Windows to Forms and added authorization and identity impersonation:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="sqlAuthCookie" timeout="60" path="/"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

### RSWebApp/Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.exe.config:

Added the same validation and decryption key as in Web.config for Reporting services

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey validationKey="GENERATED_VALIDATION_KEY" decryptionKey="GENERATED_DECRYPTION_KEY" validation="AES" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

### Copy files to right places

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.SQL2016\Reporting Services\RSWebApp:

1. Copy Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.exe.config

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.SQL2016\Reporting Services\ReportServer:
 1. Copy the other three config files mentioned above
 2. Copy Login.aspx and .cs
 3. Copy Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.dll into /bin

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the preview version of SSRS with Power BI and the preview does not have support for multiple instances.

When I changed the files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\RSServer\ReportServer instead and then restarted "SQL Server Reporting Services - Standalone" I got the logon prompt

Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the MachineKey from Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost.exe.config file (RSWebApp directory) to the web.config file (ReportServer directory).